# from php string to mysql date

Tags: php, mysql, date

What I'm trying to do is insert credit card info from a form to my mysql database.
First of all, 
the input format for the expire date will be `MM / YY`(with or without spaces) on the form and i'm trying to concat the `"20"` string to the year but I always get `"20 YY"` as a result, which cannot be recognised from mysql as a date.

I want to get the expire date to fit a format so later on it can be altered into a MySQL format. Any ideas?

This is my code so far:

```
<?php 
                $cc_number="";
                $cc_expire="";
                $cc_cvc="";
                $cc_number=$_POST['number'];
                $cc_expire=$_POST['expiry'];
                $cc_cvc=$_POST['cvc'];
                $cc_pid=$_SESSION['pid'];

                /*edit the expire date*/
                $pieces=explode("/", $cc_expire);
                $expire_dd="01";
                $expire_mm=$pieces[0];

                $expire_yy="20".$pieces[1];
                $expire_yy=trim($expire_yy, "\x00..\x1F");

                //$cc_expire = $expire_yy.$expire_mm.$expire_dd;
                //$cc_expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $cc_expire)));
                echo "expire_yy = ".$expire_yy;
                //echo "cc_expire = ".$cc_expire;
                if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                    if (empty($cc_number) || empty($cc_cvc) || empty($cc_expire)) {
                        echo "<p align='center'><font color='red'><br><br><br><br>All fields are mandatory.</font></p>";
                    }
                    else {
                        $cc_expire = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cc_expire));
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO credit_card (credit_card_number, cvc, expiration_date, pid)
                                VALUES ('$cc_number', '$cc_cvc', '$cc_expire', $cc_pid)";
                        if ($dbconn->query($sql)) {
                            //echo "<script> window.location.assign('../card.php'); </script>";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<p align='center'><font color='red'><br><br><br><br>Something went wrong.</font></p>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

I want for all the cards to get a mySql DATE format which will be 01-MM-YYYY.

Comment: Whats output of `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: Mysql date format is yyyy-mm-dd, not `01-MM-YYYY`. What is `expiration_date`, varchar? What is `$cc_expire` in your example code? You are also open to SQL injections with this..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the data looks like in $cc_expire you may need to parse it first so this first:

```
 $cc_expire = "28-".str_replace(" ","-",cc_expire);
```

Which should give dd-mm-yyyy format (I've had a issue using '/' before when changing  dateformat)

Then do:

```
  $mysqldate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($cc_expire));
```

This should convert the cc_expire to mysql format ready for insertion.

Comment: this is what I ultimately need. but the first step in order to get there is to create the date variable. which so far is `20 20` **with a space** which i dont need.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime() should work for you. learn more here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp